# MySQL avoiding GROUP BY columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've the following query that does a group by on 2 columns from different tables. I understand this can cause performance issues. I'm unsure how to go about optimizing this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Query**

```
SELECT tableA.col AS tableAcol, 
       tableB.col AS tableBcol, 
       SUM(tableB.count) AS total
FROM tableB, tableA
WHERE tableB.uid = tableA.uid 
AND tableA.eid=? 
GROUP BY tableA.col, tableB.col
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery that performs partial sums, to reduce the size of the `JOIN` that sum in the outer query.

```
SELECT tableA.col AS tableAcol
       tableBgrouped.col AS tableBcol,
       SUM(tableBgrouped.count) AS total
FROM tableA
JOIN (SELECT uid, col, SUM(count) AS count
      FROM tableB
      GROUP BY uid, col) AS tableBgrouped
ON tableA.uid = tableBgrouped.uid
WHERE tableA.eid = ?
GROUP BY tableAcol, tableBcol
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.`col` AS tableAcol
       B.`col` AS tableBcol,
       SUM(B.`count`) AS total
FROM tableA A
JOIN (SELECT B1.`uid`, B1.`col`, SUM(B1.`count`) AS count
      FROM tableB B
      GROUP BY B1.`uid`, B1.`col`) AS B
ON A.`uid` = B.`uid`
WHERE A.`eid` = ?
GROUP BY A.`col`, B.`col`
```